# How to fix Visual Studio Project looking for a non existent header file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have started with a template VS project, and after some modifications, I'm getting an error about an none existent header file which I don't have and don't want. How can I fix this and tell Visual Studio to forget about that header file.

```
Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?
```

This? I just have one simple main.cpp file in my project.

No matter what I do, it is inside that .vxcproj file:

```
<ClCompile>
  <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
  <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
  <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;MYSCSTUDY_EXPORTS;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
  <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
  <PrecompiledHeaderFile>pch.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
</ClCompile>
```

Comment: In the project's settings, can you turn off (i.e. "don't use") precompiled headers?

Comment: Nope. It just does not want to give up on that header file. This is insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove "use" in precompiled headers.

project property -> c/c++ -> all options -> precompiled heder -> not using precompiled headers.

**EDIT**(Thanks to the comment)

keep in mind to do that change for all project configurations.

Comment: I did that. Still same.

Comment: fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?

Comment: @mbilyanov Did you make that change for all project configurations? Sounds like you're changing the settings for one configuration but building another.

Comment: Ok. That was the problem. Honestly coming from another editor, I'm completely amazed how people are using this Visual Studio thing. Thank you!

Comment: @mbilyanov It's the best IDE out there IMHO